# Variable is not usind in link?

Tags: php, hyperlink, location

I need som help - I really cant see where I do the mistake!

I need to below code to remember the variable for loading the next page. The page loads using a link like:

```
editgallery.php?folder=big_fish&id=459
```

Now I want the below codes to remember the folder variable: big_fish for generating the next link. In the bottom of the codes I use a "location" to load the next page. It looks like:

```
header("Location: galleries.php?folder".$folder." ");
```

It should send the user back to the page they came from when clicking "update" in the form in the below codes:

```
if(!$_POST["submit"])
{
include "header.php";
$query = mysql_query("select name, type, folder, description , displaydate from galleries where id = '".$_GET["id"]."' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$name = $row[0];
$type = $row[1];
$folder = $row[2];
$description = $row[3];
$displaydate = $row[4];
?>

<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" name="myform" id="myform">
<center><table width="<?=$setting["tablewidth"]?>" class="admintable" cellpadding="<?=$setting["cellpadding"]?>">
<tr>
    <td class="adminheader" colspan="2">&nbsp;<b>Edit Gallery:</b></td>
</tr>

        <tr>    
            <td class="admincell">&nbsp;Name:</td>
            <td class="admincell">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$name?>" size="40"></td>
</tr>
        <tr>    
            <td class="admincell">&nbsp;Category:</td><td class="admincell">

<?=$folder?>

</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td class="admincell">&nbsp;Display Date:</td>
<td class="admincell" align="">
    <input style="border-style:hidden" type="text" value="<?=$displaydate?>" id="from" id="<?php echo $_REQUEST["from"]; ?>" name="displaydate" size="40">
    (yyyymmdd - Like <?=date('Ymd');?> or <?=date('Y-m-d');?>)</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td class="admincell">&nbsp;Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="admincell">

<textarea id="Enter you description of the photo set here" name="description"><?=$description?></textarea></td>
<!-- http://ckeditor.com/ -->          
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
            </script>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="admincell" colspan="2"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_GET["id"]?>"><center>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"></center></td>
</tr>

</table></center>
</form><center>
<p>



</table></center>

<?
include "footer.php";
}
else
{

mysql_query("update galleries set name = '".$_POST["name"]."', description = '".$_POST["description"]."' , displaydate = '" . $_POST["displaydate"] . "' where id = '".$_POST["id"]."' ");

header("Location: galleries.php?folder".$folder." ");
//header("Location: galleries.php");
}
```

Can anyone see why the $folder name from the link is not saved for the location link - why cant the codes "transfer" it from the `editgallery.php?folder=big_fish&id=459` link and to the location like: `("Location: galleries.php?folder".$folder." ");`

Please advice.

Comment: Instead of using `header`, switch it to an echo - what does it print out? Does it look like the URL you want to generate?

Comment: @andrewsi how will you use an Echo to generate the next page using the codes: galleries.php?folder".$folder." ?

Comment: You literally swap `header` for `echo`. It's a debugging tool - you're testing the code to see what it's producing. Once you can see what you're generating, you can figure out what needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to re-write my answer here.

Your code could use some cleanup. Here are some items that I would fix:

```
<input style="border-style:hidden" 
       type="text" 
       value="<?=$displaydate?>" 
       id="from" 
       id="<?php echo $_REQUEST["from"]; ?>" 
       name="displaydate" 
       size="40">
```

You have two id's there. No bueno.

```
<textarea id="Enter you description of the photo set here" name="description"><?=$description?></textarea>
```

Not really a good idea to have your ID contain spaces. Did you mean to use the title attribute?

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_GET["id"]?>">
```

This is good. And I think this is where your main problem lies. **You need to add another hidden input with folder**

```
<input type="hidden" name="folder" value="<?=$_GET["folder"]?>">
```

This way, when the form is posted, the folder will be sent in the form of `$_POST['folder']`.

Then, here:

```
header("Location: galleries.php?folder".$folder." ");
```

Should become:

```
header("Location: galleries.php?folder=".$_POST['folder']);
```

Try that and let us know what happens please.

Comment: Thanks, but its still not working. The wird thing is when I use a location link like: header("Location: galleries.php?folder=".$id." "); then it show the ID number. This Means that its working, but not with "folder" only with "id". Can you see why?

Comment: @GernerChristensen what is the output of the query? I'm wondering if the folder column is NULL when you execute the query.

Comment: @ joseph4tw if I change to: header("Location: `galleries.php?folder=".$_GET['folder']);` then I still dont get the variable, the generated URL looks like: `galleries.php?folder=`. The column is not NULL, its all filled with info in the database. The page is generated using a URL like: `editgallery.php?folder=big_fish&id=459` if I then change the link in the Location to: `galleries.php?folder=".$folder."&id=".$id."` then the id variable us used to generate the next page so the URL looks like: `galleries.php?folder=&id=459` but the folder variable (big_fish) is not in the URL, can you see why?

Comment: @GernerChristensen i just re-wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an equals sign:

```
header("Location: galleries.php?folder".$folder." ");
```

should be

```
header("Location: galleries.php?folder=".$folder." ");
```

You might want to consider using [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to handle building the URL.

Comment: @ Kryten Thanks, but its still not working. The wird thing is when I use a location link like: header("Location: galleries.php?folder=".$id." "); then it show the ID number. This Means that its working, but not with "folder" only with "id". Can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and have typos:

```
header("Location: galleries.php?folder=".$folder." ");
                                      ^---missing
```

Essentially you're generating a link that looks like

```
 galleries.php?folderfoo
```

instead of

```
 galleries.php?folder=foo
```

Comment: Thanks, but its still not working. The wird thing is when I use a location link like: header("Location: galleries.php?folder=".$id." "); then it show the ID number. This Means that its working, but not with "folder" only with "id". Can you see why?

Comment: You mean you see `galleries.php?id` in the browser? Nothing in this code could cause that. Do you have any rewrites happening on the server?

Comment: @Mars B sorry for not to be clear. I mean the page is generated using a URL like: `editgallery.php?folder=big_fish&id=459` if I then change the link in the Location to: `galleries.php?folder=".$folder."&id=".$id."` then the id variable is used to generate the next page so the URL looks like: `galleries.php?folder=&id=459` but the folder variable (big_fish) is not in the URL, can you see why? It should look like `galleries.php?folder=big_fish&id=459`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the missing `=`, I don't see how you are setting your variable (or database connection...).

You probably want something like:

```
header("Location: galleries.php?folder=" . $_GET['folder']);
```

You should also switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you have an sql injection problem.

**Edit:** Note that when a POST request is made / `$_POST["submit"]` is set, only the last two lines of the script are executed:

- A mysql query without a database connection
- A `header()` call with an undefined `$folder` variable.

Comment: Thanks, but its still not working. The wird thing is when I use a location link like: header("Location: galleries.php?folder=".$id." "); then it show the ID number. This Means that its working, but not with "folder" only with "id". Can you see why?

Comment: @GernerChristensen As far as I can see, only 2 lines of code get executed on a POST request so if there is more happening, you need to show it.

Comment: All codes are in the first post - nothing more is going on. The page is generated using a URL like: `editgallery.php?folder=big_fish&id=459` if I then change the link in the Location to: `galleries.php?folder=".$folder."&id=".$id."` then the id variable is used to generate the next page so the URL looks like: `galleries.php?folder=&id=459` but the folder variable (big_fish) is not in the URL, can you see why?

Comment: @GernerChristensen Look at the flow of the script, if a POST request is made, only the last two lines of your script are executed: A mysql query without a database connection and a `header` call with an undefined `$folder` variable. Just use `$_GET['folder']` like in my answer.

Comment: I understand about the POST (not sure how to change is its working with the POST!) but if I use the code: `header("Location: galleries.php?folder=".$_GET['folder']."");` the variable from "folder" is not included in the URL and it looks like: `galleries.php?folder=` so some how something is blocking for the $_GET[] so it cant "see" it in the URL `editgallery.php?folder=adela_urygova&id=17`its diffecult to explain but hope you know what I mean.